# geom_boxplot IQR computation using grouping/cutting column

Tags: r, statistics, ggplot2, boxplot

I want to use `geom_boxplot()` to display IQR on my data.

If i have a grouping variable to compute stat by data bloc, i need to pre-compute a dataframe with `ddply` which contain all data (IQR, etc.) for each data bloc ? or can i use some `group=` instruction to force computation of all statistics before geom_boxplot() automaticly display it ?

Structure of my data is equal to this sample, with grouping/cutting variable for stat computation is `replication` :

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection("city population replication 
1 1 2500 1
2 2 3000 1
3 3 1200 1
4 1 2200 2
5 2 3100 2
6 3 1800 2
"))
```

For example, i want to display the `geom_boxplot()` for replication 1 population, then replication 2 population.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the kind of plot you are looking for?

Here, the numeric variable `replication` is transformed to a factor to generate separate boxplots for each level.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = as.factor(replication), y = population)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

---

You will obtain a similar plot (with a numeric x scale) if you don't transform `replication` to a factor but use `aes(group = replication)` as an argument for `geom_boxplot`:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = replication, y = population)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(group = replication))
```

[image]